# How to include PNG image with transparent background with CSS

Tags: css

When I am using CSS3 to include a PNG file with a transparent background it the background is autometically being converted to white. How do I keep it transparent?

Comment: what is the background-color of the body? as @AryanFirouzyan said post your code,it will be easy helping you.

Comment: try something like this 
       
background: transparent url("img.png") no-repeat center;

Answer (score 1):

CSS does not manipulate PNG files in any way as you're making it sound. Without seeing your code, we can only assume that the white background you describe is the background color of the element the image is placed in.

**If the image itself is being used as the background**, use this code:

```css
element {
background: transparent url(image.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

**If the image is not being used as a background** and is merely an image element placed within a div, then the background color of the parent div should be set to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

i know that have passed 2 years, but i will answer the same way.

you have to use a PNG image to garant that has no-background, so you can overlay any text/image using your no-background image.

i just use <img src"..."> and it works very fine here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).